# Qt Remote Objects' interoperability between operating systems

Tags: qt, qtremoteobjects

Can 2 Qt applications running on 2 different OSes -- one on Windows and the other one on macOS for instance -- communicate using QtRO?

I assume they can, but can anybody confirm this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible for two Qt applications running on different operating systems to communicate using Qt Remote Objects.

yout will need :

- QtRO server with `QRemoteObjectHost`
- QtRO cient with `QRemoteObjectNode`

Then you can use the client to access the exposed `QObjects` and invoke methods on them.

For more information on how to use QtRO, you can refer to the QtRO documentation: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtremoteobjects-index.html

Comment: Could you provide some material to support your assertion please?

Comment: You could use TCP/IP so you just have to configure both applications to use Qt Remote Objects and connect them via their IP address and communication port. https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtremoteobjects-external-schemas.html